# Tab behaviour between :o and :cd

Tags: autocompletion, tabbed-user-interface

When I use `:cd` command in gvim it allows to complete the directories with a simple `Tab` press. However with `:o` command I only get `^I`.

How can I migrate the same bahavior from `:cd` to `:o`?

Comment: As usual: `:help :o`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `:o` command does something completely different, where tabs wouldn't really make sense:

```
This command is in Vi, but Vim only simulates it:

                                                    *:o* *:op* *:open*
:[range]o[pen]              Works like |:visual|: end Ex mode.
                            {Vi: start editing in open mode}

:[range]o[pen] /pattern/    As above, additionally move the cursor to the
                            column where "pattern" matches in the cursor
                            line.

Vim does not support open mode, since it's not really useful.  For those
situations where ":open" would start open mode Vim will leave Ex mode, which
allows executing the same commands, but updates the whole screen instead of
only one line.
```

For example, try pressing <kbd>Q</kbd> (that is, <kbd>Shift+q</kbd>). Then type `o` in the prompt. You should be back in normal mode. Now insert "This is some text" onto your current line, press <kbd>Q</kbd> again, and type `o /x/`. You should be back in normal mode, with your cursor on the `x`.

Using `:o` with a filename appears to work the same way as `:e`. However, I wouldn't rely on this, since it appears to be undocumented.

Answer (score 1):

Vim only includes the `:o[pen]` command for legacy reasons.  The command you're looking for is `:e[dit]`, which has all the completion behavior you would expect.